# Selenium. Button is focused, however, not clicked

Tags: java, selenium, click

I am using selenium, Firefox driver. My Java code:

```
List<WebElement> act = test.findAllElements(toBasketButton);
assertTrue("ToBasket button not found", act != null);

WebElement lastBtn = act.get(act.size()-1);
assertTrue(lastBtn.isEnabled());    

lastBtn.click();
```

I can see that the button I want to be clicked is focused (color is changed), however, further code is being executed without a click on lastBtn. Why is it so and how can I force this button to be clicked?

Comment: assertTrue("ToBasket button not found", act != null); Does this work? IIRC the return is an empty list if it cannot find any matching elements, not null. Print out the list and see if it actually finds the button you want to click and not some other button.

Comment: Show some html please. Also, what is "test"? WebElement does not have method findAllElements.

Answer (score 0):

what is coming in lastBtn. Is it correct that it is getting button which needs to be clicked.

For clicking a button you can use.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.click(lastBtn);
```